# Spring Data REST javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have tow Entities:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer userId;

    private String userName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Degree> degreeList;

}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "degrees")
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public Degree {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer degreeId;

    private String degreeTitle;
}
```

RestResources are:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRestRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

and then:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "degrees", path = "degrees")
public interface DegreeRestRepository extends CrudRepository<Degree, Integer> {
}
```

I have to add new `bar` in `barList` of foo using `https://www.myhost.com/api/users/{userId}/degreeList` endpoint as shown in image:

[image]

but I am getting:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-17T05:16:51.520+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction",
    "path": "/api/users/4/degreeList"
}
```

I have searched and found that I have to save `Degree` then update `degreeList`, how can I do that please guide

Comment: any additional logs to investigate ?

Comment: You mean `StackTrace`?

Comment: yes additional information from the stacktrace

Comment: How about your check your mapping? Corresponding manytoone in  degree?

Comment: @tksilicon there is no any `@ManyToOne` mapping in `Degree`!

Comment: You have one to many, what is the corresponding mapping in degrees?

Comment: @tksilicon I am using uni directional `@OneToMany` means only `@OneToMany` in `User`, there is no any `@ManyToOne` mapping in `Degree`

Comment: bidirectional association is not required...

Comment: Then you have to think about your design and @transactional annotation. Surely, your problem is from there.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data REST is URI-based (following the HATEOAS rules). If you want to add "degree" to "degreeList", indeed you first need to create the degree:

> HTTP POST to `https://www.myhost.com/api/degrees`

The request body has to be of content type `application/json`

After that, you get back the Degree ID in the response. You use this ID to add the Degree to the list:

> HTTP POST to `https://www.myhost.com/api/users/{userId}/degreeList`

Important: this time the request content type is `text/uri-list`! The body must be plain text and should just contain the URI

```
https://www.myhost.com/api/degrees/{degreeId}
```

Comment: if I make a post request like: `{ "href": "https://www.myhost.com/api/degrees/41" }` at `https://www.myhost.com/api/users/45/degreeList`, it does not add new degree and clears previous added degrees in the list as well.

Comment: at `https://www.myhost.com/api/degrees` I am saving new degree successfully!

Comment: { "href": "https://www.myhost.com/api/degrees/41" } is not the correct request body format. This one is in application/json, while you just need to use plain text as described in my answer :). Just use the URL string in your request body and indicate Content-Type to be type/uri-list. Then it'll work fine.